# Tkinter : I need to stop generating this "main" function called "pyrotechnik" when i press any button

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, canvas, tkinter

Hi guys I'm new to programming and I'm working with python at school.
Currently I'm working with tkinter and I have a little problem with this exercise.
Timer starts at 60, when it hits 0, it "explodes". If i click the right wire, it will tell me i've made it but if i click the wrong one it "explodes". The problem is, when i click any button it keeps generating the main function and I have no idea how to stop it. I hope someone can help me :)

```
import tkinter 
from random import * 
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(bg='White', width=400, height=200) 
canvas.pack()

stop = randint(1, 4)
timer = 61

def pyrotechnik():
    global timer, stop
    canvas.delete('all')
    timer -= 1
    canvas.create_text(200, 100, font='Arial 20 bold', text=timer, fill='Red')
    if timer == 0:
        canvas.delete('all')
        canvas.create_text(200, 100, font='Arial 20 bold', text='Bomb has exploded', fill='Red')
    else:
        canvas.after(1000, pyrotechnik) 
print(stop)


def blue():    
    canvas.delete('all')
    if stop == 1:
        canvas.create_text(200, 100, font='Arial 20 bold', text='Thank god you"ve made it', fill='Green')
    else:
        canvas.create_text(200, 100, font='Arial 20 bold', text='BOOM', fill='Orange') 
def red():
    canvas.delete('all')
    if stop == 2:
        canvas.create_text(200, 100, font='Arial 20 bold', text='Thank god you"ve made it', fill='Green')
    else:
        canvas.create_text(200, 100, font='Arial 20 bold', text='BOOM', fill='Orange')

def yellow():
    canvas.delete('all')
    if stop == 3:
        canvas.create_text(200, 100, font='Arial 20 bold', text='Thank god you"ve made it', fill='Green')
    else:
        canvas.create_text(200, 100, font='Arial 20 bold', text='BOOM', fill='Orange')

def green():
    canvas.delete('all')
    if stop == 4:
        canvas.create_text(200, 100, font='Arial 20 bold', text='Thank god you"ve made it', fill='Green')
    else:
        canvas.create_text(200, 100, font='Arial 20 bold', text='BOOM', fill='Orange')


button1 = tkinter.Button(text='Blue wire', command=blue, bg='SkyBlue') button1.pack()

button2 = tkinter.Button(text='Red wire', command=red, bg='Red') button2.pack()

button3 = tkinter.Button(text='Yellow wire', command=yellow, bg='Yellow') button3.pack()

button4 = tkinter.Button(text='Green wire', command=green, bg='Green') button4.pack()

pyrotechnik()
```

Comment: Please consider [creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in its current state your redundantly long code snippet has syntax errors, and incomplete.

Comment: You can update the text on a canvas without having to delete and redraw it from scratch. `canvas.itemconfig(txt,text="Hello!!")` will change the text. txt is the value returned when you create the text object initially i.e. `txt = canvas.create_text(200, 100,  text='BOOM')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only do you need to delete everything on the canvas, but you also need to cancel the order to update the screen. The following version of your program should work properly. Please note the changes.

```
import tkinter
from random import *

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(bg='White', width=400, height=200)
canvas.pack()

stop = randint(1, 4)
timer = 61
handle = None


def pyrotechnik():
    global timer, stop, handle
    canvas.delete('all')
    timer -= 1
    canvas.create_text(200, 100, font='Arial 20 bold', text=timer, fill='Red')
    if timer == 0:
        canvas.delete('all')
        canvas.create_text(200, 100, font='Arial 20 bold',
                           text='Bomb has exploded', fill='Red')
    else:
        handle = canvas.after(1000, pyrotechnik)


print(stop)


def blue():
    canvas.delete('all')
    canvas.after_cancel(handle)
    if stop == 1:
        canvas.create_text(200, 100, font='Arial 20 bold',
                           text="Thank god you've made it", fill='Green')
    else:
        canvas.create_text(200, 100, font='Arial 20 bold', text='BOOM',
                           fill='Orange')


def red():
    canvas.delete('all')
    canvas.after_cancel(handle)
    if stop == 2:
        canvas.create_text(200, 100, font='Arial 20 bold',
                           text="Thank god you've made it", fill='Green')
    else:
        canvas.create_text(200, 100, font='Arial 20 bold', text='BOOM',
                           fill='Orange')


def yellow():
    canvas.delete('all')
    canvas.after_cancel(handle)
    if stop == 3:
        canvas.create_text(200, 100, font='Arial 20 bold',
                           text="Thank god you've made it", fill='Green')
    else:
        canvas.create_text(200, 100, font='Arial 20 bold', text='BOOM',
                           fill='Orange')


def green():
    canvas.delete('all')
    canvas.after_cancel(handle)
    if stop == 4:
        canvas.create_text(200, 100, font='Arial 20 bold',
                           text="Thank god you've made it", fill='Green')
    else:
        canvas.create_text(200, 100, font='Arial 20 bold', text='BOOM',
                           fill='Orange')


button1 = tkinter.Button(text='Blue wire', command=blue, bg='SkyBlue')
button1.pack()

button2 = tkinter.Button(text='Red wire', command=red, bg='Red')
button2.pack()

button3 = tkinter.Button(text='Yellow wire', command=yellow, bg='Yellow')
button3.pack()

button4 = tkinter.Button(text='Green wire', command=green, bg='Green')
button4.pack()

pyrotechnik()
tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: This actually works! Thank you very much.I dont know the main loop function and the handle function but it works! Ill look up those two and read something about them

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create GUI applications, you would do well to learn about object-oriented programming. Designing your programs with classes helps keep your code organized if used properly. While my previous answer may have worked fine for what you were trying to accomplish, my recommendation would be to learn how to write your code in the following way instead:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import random
import tkinter
import tkinter.font


class Pyrotechnic(tkinter.Frame):
    __DEFAULT = object()

    @classmethod
    def main(cls):
        tkinter.NoDefaultRoot()
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        root.title(cls.__name__)
        root.resizable(False, False)
        self = cls(root)
        self.grid()
        root.mainloop()

    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf=__DEFAULT, **kw):
        if cnf is self.__DEFAULT:
            cnf = {}
        super().__init__(master, cnf, **kw)
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self, bg='#FFFFFF', width=400, height=200)
        self.canvas.grid(sticky=tkinter.NSEW)
        self.stop = random.randint(1, 4)
        self.timer = 60
        self.buttons = []
        for wire_id, (name, color) in enumerate((
                ('Blue', '#7777FF'),
                ('Red', '#FF0000'),
                ('Yellow', '#FFFF00'),
                ('Green', '#00FF00')), 1):
            new_button = tkinter.Button(
                self,
                text=f'{name} Wire',
                command=self.create_button_handler(wire_id),
                bg=color
            )
            new_button.grid(sticky=tkinter.NSEW, padx=5, pady=5)
            self.buttons.append(new_button)
        self.after_handle = None
        self.font = tkinter.font.Font(
            self,
            family='Arial',
            size=20,
            weight='bold'
        )
        self.game_over = False
        self.timer_loop()

    def echo(self, text, fill):
        self.canvas.create_text(200, 100, font=self.font, text=text, fill=fill)

    def create_button_handler(self, wire_id):
        def button_handler():
            if not self.game_over:
                self.canvas.delete(tkinter.ALL)
                self.after_cancel(self.after_handle)
                if self.stop == wire_id:
                    self.echo("Thank god you've made it!", '#00FF00')
                else:
                    self.echo('BOOM', '#FF7700')
                self.game_over = True

        return button_handler

    def timer_loop(self):
        self.canvas.delete(tkinter.ALL)
        if self.timer > 0:
            self.echo(self.timer, '#FF0000')
            self.timer -= 1
            self.after_handle = self.after(1000, self.timer_loop)
        else:
            self.echo('Bomb has exploded!', '#FF0000')
            self.game_over = True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Pyrotechnic.main()
```

Comment: I totallly should.. Thank you for your time :-) I really appreciate it !